# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, "The underlying connection was closed unexpectedly", but it works with open HTTPDebugger

Tags: vb.net, sockets, ssl, server, socketexception

So I communicate with a server of my company. I send data (to save in a *.csv file) and receive data (for version checking, just a string).
From one second to the other (without changing the code nor anything on the server side), I get this exception from my code:

[image: Thrown exception]

"*The underlying connection was closed unexpectedly. Error while sending data.* -->" [...] "*Data cant be read from the connection: An existing connection was closed by the remote host* --->"

**This is my code:**

```
' Build data
' ...

' Create request and write data
Dim Agent As String = "> agent goes here <"
Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(Url), HttpWebRequest)
Request.UserAgent = Agent
Request.Method = "POST"
Request.ContentLength = outData.Length
Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Request.KeepAlive = False

Request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11                                     ' Fix 1
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3         ' Fix 2
                                                    Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True                             ' Fix 3
Request.Timeout = 1000000000                                                        ' Fix 4
Request.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000000000                                               ' Fix 5
Request.ClientCertificates.Add(New X509Certificate())                               ' Fix 6

Using Stream As IO.Stream = Request.GetRequestStream                                ' Exception still gets thrown here
Stream.Write(outData, 0, outData.Length)
End Using
```

As you can see, I already tried many different ways to fix (and to be honest, I dont really know what I do, I still need to get more knowledge in this field)

The interesting thing is, when I start my [HTTPDebugger](https://www.httpdebugger.com/), the error does not occur and I have no problems at all, everything works just fine.

So my guess is that the HTTPDebugger somehow installs/intercepts with a certain certificate which I dont know and then the server accepts the connection again.
But how can I provide such a certificate, where to get it, and which should I use. And if thats not the problem: What could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that **updating from .NET 4.5 to .NET 4.7.2** and compiling again solved the problem.

I dont know why this problem happened and how it could have been solved otherwise, but this fixed it for me.

Comment: Could be that the server admin enforced [TLS 1.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client) or similar; I don't think .NET 4.5 supports it

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That may be possible, though he said nothing changed.